# xargs and kill not working together to kill specific processes

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a Docker container running Red Hat 6.8 and I have several Java processes running. On other machines with the same OS, I have used a command similar to the following to find and kill all Java processes:

```
ps -ef | grep 'java' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

However, on this machine, it gives me the following error:

```
xargs: kill: No such file or directory
```

Taking off the "| xargs kill -9" does work and shows me the PIDs of the processes I want to kill but for some reason, the command will not work all together.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Better you use `pkill -f java`

Comment: What happens if you just type `kill someID`? The problem seems to be that it can't execute the `kill` command.

Comment: There is something wrong with your kill or xargs command. This simple test works fine in my Debian 9 : `ps -ef |awk '/[g]eany/{print $2}' |xargs kill -9` PS: `grep 'geany' |grep -v 'grep'` can be written as `grep '[g]eany'`.

Comment: or `killall -9 java`

Comment: Specifically, `xargs` needs a `kill` command to exist in `PATH`. It can't run a shell builtin.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I am aware of other similar commands but was curious what was wrong with this one. @WumpusQ.Wumbley - that seems to be the problem! For some reason, inside this Docker container, /bin/kill does not exist (though for some reason I could run kill though "which kill" gave nothing back. I can't mark your comment here as the solution but if you make an answer, I can do so.

Comment: or replace `xargs kill -9` by `xargs echo kill -9 | bash`. This works independently whether `/bin/kill` exists or does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `xargs` can't find the `kill` command. It needs to be in your `PATH`, probably in `/bin` and/or `/usr/bin`. You wouldn't notice it was missing when you run the `kill` command directly from the shell, because most shells have a `kill` builtin.

Also, I agree with the comments by other users about the overall idea. There are less hacky ways to do this (`killall`, `pkill`, anything that doesn't involve `grep` that's relying on luck to avoid matching the wrong part of the `ps output...)

Comment: Thank you - the problem is that for some reason, in this Docker container /bin/kill does not exist. I've copied it there from the host system and things are working fine. My main reason for using a command like this is so that it will work on all variants of Unix I work with (Linux, AIX, HP-UX, Sun) and I've found that not all of those support the "easier" to use commands.

Answer (score 3):

That's the top result in Google about this specific issue, if not the only one, so I just wanted to note it here after two years: `kill` is bundled in [`util-linux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package (in RHEL) or [`procps`](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) package (in Debian) along with bunch of other utilities. Installing that package in the container solves the issue.